# How to change 'et al.' into something like 'and others' for a single in-text citation only (apacite + natbib)?

Tags: citing, natbib, apacite

I am using apacite with the natbibapa option, and for some individual in-text citations with 5+ authors I'd like to have the option to chance the citation into a phrase like this:

```
Author and colleagues (2019) conducted an experiment...
```

or this:

```
...as shown by Author and coworkers (2019)
```

However, as shown by the MWE below, the only options I can think of are either having 'et al.' in my in-text citation (which is not what I want), or - a very ugly workaround - just citing only the year 'officially' (but then my author name is not 'clickable' and I have to use very unofficial brackets around the citeyear command).

P.S. I have looked at all the other 'et al.' topics and I think my question is not a duplicate because this is about individual citations and not about the formatting of 'et al.' in general, but please correct me if I'm wrong!

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
    @article{Author2019Article,
        title={Article title},
        author={Author, Andrew and Buthor, Bas and Cuthor, Chris and Duthor, Derk and Euthor, Eric and Futhor, Fred},
        year={2019}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\citet*{Author2019Article} conducted an experiment...\\
...as shown by Author and coworkers (\citeyear{Author2019Article})

\bibliography{Ref}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term for "et al." (in citations) is saved in `apacite`'s `\BOthers` macro. We can temporarily redefine it to say "and colleagues" or something else. It might be convenient to pack up this redefinition in a new macro called `\etalchange`. We keep the redefinition local by enclosing it and the `\cite` it should refer to in curly braces, like

```
{\etalchange\citet*{Author2019Article}} conducted an experiment
```

In full

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\etalchange}{%
  \renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{and colleagues\hbox{}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Author2019Article,
  title  = {Article title},
  author = {Author, Andrew and Buthor, Bas and Cuthor, Chris
            and Duthor, Derk and Euthor, Eric and Futhor, Fred},
  year   = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
{\etalchange\citet*{Author2019Article}} conducted an experiment

\citep{Author2019Article}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Author and colleagues (2019) conducted an experiment (Author et al., 2019)]